# Skype bot detecta quando receber mensagem

Tags: c#, winforms, skype

É o seguinte eu tenho andado a procura como poderei fazer um bot que responde quando receba uma mensagem de alguém, eu encontrei um tutorial mas não consegui fazer com que o bot respondesse apesar do bot responder no tutorial.

Este é o código que tenho para o bot responder.

```
public void MsgStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
    {

        if (Status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived || Status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent)
        {

            string msg = pMessage.Body;
            Chat c = pMessage.Chat;

            if (msg.StartsWith(Trigger))
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + "command" + "'" + msg + "'" + "from" + pMessage.Sender.Handle);
                msg = msg.Remove(0, 1).ToLower();
            }
            if (msg == Trigger + "help")
            {
                c.SendMessage("working");
            }
            else if (msg == "hello")
            {
                c.SendMessage("hello");
            }
            else if (msg == "oi" || msg == "ola" || msg == "olá")
            {
                c.SendMessage("Oi");
            }

        }

    }
```

É assim que ele começa 
`oSkype.MessageStatus += new SKYPE4COMLib._ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(MsgStatus);`

Comment: Qual o link do tutorial? O sistema operacional e a versão do skype do tutorial são os mesmos que o seu?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow sim mas eu tive que converter o código todo de vb para c# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahkuYT7-wdU

Comment: Depois de muita pesquisa encontrei este [site](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-create-a-skype-auto-talk-bot-c.1413931/) que explica bem e funciona espero que vos ajude.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Assim, a sua pergunta precisaria ter um problema claro e objetivo. Você diz que o Bot não responde, mas ele executa? Você depurou o código? Há alguma mensagem de erro? Sem esses detalhes, dificilmente alguém conseguira te ajudar.

Comment: @LuizVieira já la vão semanas achas que me lembro. não é o melhor momento para perguntar isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa encontrei este [site](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-create-a-skype-auto-talk-bot-c.1413931/) que explica bem e funciona espero que vos ajude.
Para o caso de o link estar offline faz-se o seguinte:

usem as seguintes dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Depois fazem download da SKYPE4COMLib Dll (Não sei onde encontrar) e adicionem a seguinte linha

`using SKYPE4COMLib;`

Depois declarasse o Skype Constructor

```
private Skype MySkype = new Skype();
```

Depois tem de fazer Attach ao skype usando

```
MySkype.Attach(5, false);
```

Este código pode ser usado em botões ou quando a form faz load dependendo do que o que voçes querem, Não aconçelho a por para conectar assim que a form faz load porque se o skype estiver fechado o programa pode dar crash aconçeho tambem a por dentro de um try porque se não conseguir vai dar erro.

Depois voçes usam o seguinte codigo

```
void MySkype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
        {
            if (pMessage.Body[0].ToString() == "@") // Check if it is a command, @ can be anything that you want.
            {
                string Command = pMessage.Body.Substring(1, pMessage.Body.Length - 1); // Basicaly remove @ from it.
                if (pMessage.Sender.Handle != MySkype.CurrentUserHandle) // Check if the sender is not yourself.
                    MySkype.SendMessage(pMessage.Sender.Handle, ProcessCommand(Command)); // Send the message back.
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Messagesent.");
            }
        }

        private string ProcessCommand(string cmd)
        {
            switch (cmd)
            {
                case "help":
                    return "The commands are: blablabla...";
                case "LOL":
                    return "(chuckle)";
                default:
                    return "This is not a command.\nSend '@help' for help.";
            }
        }
```

O que vai fazer é verificar se a menssagem começa com @ senão começar não vai fazer nada se comçar vai para o switch e se for por exemplo @help a menssagem que recebeu ele vai executar

```
case "help":
                    return "The commands are: blablabla...";
```

O que vai fazer é mandar a quem recebu uma menssagem a dizer The commands are: blablabla...
Mais alguma duvida ou coisas que não tenham percebido é só perguntar.